# htmx:targeterror in django project

Tags: python, html, css, django, templates

My objective is to click on a list item (an asset) to load and update a form, that is right next to the list, using htmx in django, but I am getting HTMX:Targeterror.. I believe I have given the hx-target correctly, I cannot figure out why this problem appears.. Someone, please help..

I am getting htmx:targetError when using the below code.. can u help me figure out the issue?

TEMPLATE

```
{% for asset in portfolio.children %}
            <tr id="asset-{{ asset.id }}" >
              <td class="col-md-12 col-lg-12 node-style" hx-get="{% url 'portfolio:asset-update' asset.id %}"
              hx-target="#assetUpdate" hx-swap="outerHTML">&emsp;{{ asset.name }}</td>
            </tr>
```

VIEWS.PY ASSET_UPDATE

```
def asset_update(request, id):
    asset = Asset.objects.get(id=id)
    update_asset_form = AssetForm(request.POST or None, instance=asset)

    if update_asset_form.is_valid():
        update_asset_form.save()
    context = {
        "update_asset_form": update_asset_form,
        "asset": asset,
    }
    return render(request, "portfolio/partials/02-asset-update.html", context)
```

02-ASSET-UPDATE.HTML

```
{% load crispy_forms_filters %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}

<div id="assetUpdate">
    <form method="post" class="form-group" novalidate>
        {% csrf_token %}
        {% crispy update_asset_form %}
        <button type="submit" class="bland-button-style" hx-post="{% url 'portfolio:asset-update' asset_id=asset.id %}"
            hx-target="#assetUpdate" hx-swap="outerHTML">
            <i class="fa-solid fa-cloud-arrow-down fa-lg header-icon-style portfolio-save-icon"></i>
        </button>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Where is the `#assetUpdate` element in your base template? I only see it in the partial template.

Comment: I dont have it in the base template.. My objective is to load update_asset_form onto itself (and this is located in partials).. hence, i did a hx-get of that function which renders the partial and then used hx-target to call the div.. is there anything wrong in the approach?

Comment: You misunderstand how HTMX is working. It needs a valid target element at the moment when you make a request. So please create a valid target element for the first request when you load the form in the partial template. After that you can use `#assetUpdate` target since its template has been loaded by HTMX.